# Building package in R in Windows

Tags: r, package, building

I have downloaded package `pcaL1_1.5.2.tar.gz` from the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcaL1/index.html). I am trying to compile the package  `pcaL1`

The steps I followed are

1. Install Rtools
2. Updated the PATH environment variable
3. In command prompt,I change the directory to where I downloaded the 
   package pcaL1_1.5.2.tar.gz
4. Run the command in Command prompt of Windows `R CMD INSTALL --build qtl_1.22-18.tar.gz`

I get the error `unexpected symbol in R CMD`.
Anything I missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running install.package from inside R.
Start an R session and the > prompt type

```
install.packages("pcaL1")
```